# Docker --volumes-from permissions

Tags: permissions, docker

I'm very new to Docker so I might be missing something, my data volume folder has `root` as owner.

Here is what I do (using the nginx reverse proxy):

```
# Data volume container
docker create -v <data path> --name <app>-data tianon/true
# Webapp container
docker run --volumes-from <app>-data --name <app> \
  -e VIRTUAL_HOST=<url> \
  <image> &
```

But nginx can't write into the data folder, and if I go in my container:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root       4096 Dec 16 19:03 data
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 Dec 16 18:57 doc
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Dec 16 18:57 images
```

I do a chown in my Dockerfile image, but it looks like `--volumes-from` changes that.

What should I do to give the `data` folder `www-data` ownership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory ([issue 2259](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2259#issuecomment-26564115)):

> If you `chown` the volume (on the host side) before bind-mounting it, it will work.
>
> In that case, you could do:

```
mkdir /tmp/www
chown 101:101 /tmp/www
docker run -v /tmp/www:/var/www ubuntu stat -c "%U %G" /var/www
```

> (Assuming that `101:101` is the `UID:GID` of the `www-data` user in your container.)

Note that it is not what you are doing: you are mounting an host folder in a data volume container (a `tianon/true` image, which is quite empty, [see its Dockerfile](https://github.com/tianon/dockerfiles/blob/master/true/Dockerfile)), and then mounting that data volume container into a regular container.

Still, that might work.

Comment: Well, it's working. However in this case, I don't see the point of using a data volume container. I can just mount the data volume on the host directly from the webapp container.

Comment: @Arthur I agree. I was just following what you did in your question.

Comment: I still don't see in which use case they're useful, but you fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Arthur You would be using data volume container as container exposing a VOLUME (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume), that can be mounted in other containers. The idea is to abstract completely the host filesystem, and manage that data in a dedicated container.